# Calculating Pisano periods for any integer

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, fibonacci-numbers, spoj

I recently stumbled across this SPOJ question:

http://www.spoj.com/problems/PISANO/
The question is simple. Calculate the [Pisano period](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisano_period) of a number. After I researched my way through the web, I found that a number's Pisano period can be calculated in terms of its prime factors. For prime numbers we have another method which uses Binet's formula. Is there any alternative for solving this problem?

Comment: The period is actually $ \pi(n) = k\cdot\text{ord}_n(F_{k+1}) $ where $k$ is the smallest positive integer such that $n\mid F_k$.

Comment: Proof available?

Comment: I can't give much of a proof, but this is in fact a true formula, and it's fairly obvious. So finding the first $k$ such that $n∣F_k$ is basically finding the first $0$ in the Fibonacci sequence mod a number. Once that is found, the multiplicative order part tells us how many 0's are in the sequence before the Pisano period (it is always either 1, 2 or 4), thus you multiply it by that to get the pisano period. And now that I think about it, it is kindof a useless formula because it would only be at maximum, 4 times faster than just actually calculating the sequence up to the pisano period.

Comment: The problem has the same level of difficulty as finding the order of 2 modulo an odd number $n$, that is, finding the smallest positive $m$ such that $2^m-1$ is a multiple of $n$. If you know it for the prime factors of $n$, you can get it for the prime power factors of $n$, and then for $n$ itself. But as for getting it for the primes, that's a computationally difficult problem. It is certainly no easier to do it for a prime $p$ than it is to factor $p-1$, which is, in general hard.

Answer (score 1):

Let p be a prime number > 5.  If p is 1 or 4 in the 
modulus of 5, then the Pisano period is a 
divisor of p-1.  If p is 2 or 3 in the modulus 
of 5, then the Pisano period is a divisor
of 2p+2.

Answer (score 0):

Its too late but I think This explanation is really helpful. [THE FIBONACCI SEQUENCE MODULO M By Marc Renault](https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/essays683/renault.html)